# Is Mister Rogers' Neighborhood and by extension Daniel Tiger's Neighborhood on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

When I get back from vacation in two weeks I'd like to ask a question about the significance of the name for the animated show *Daniel Tiger's Neighborhood* which is based on the make-believe characters featured on the classic American show *Mister Rogers' Neighborhood*. My hope is it would be on topic here because [Fred Rogers took pains to separate](https://www.realityblurred.com/realitytv/2018/03/mister-rogers-its-you-i-like-pbs/) the make-believe parts of his show from the real parts of his show:

> The things Fred Rogers did on purpose included insisting that Carol Spinney appear in costume as Big Bird in the Neighborhood of Make Believe only (Jim Henson wouldn’t let Spinney take the head off his costume to show that there was a person inside, but Rogers wanted to keep make believe separate from reality);

I'm concerned it will be closed as merely anthropomorphic talking animals and not true fantasy per the rules of the site. If that is the consensus then I'll likely post on Movies.SE, but I'd rather post here if possible.

To be clear my question will be about the origin story of the fictional character Daniel Tiger, and the reasons why he was chosen as the title character for the current continuation of Fred Rogers work on television.

---

Fair warning I'm going to be on vacation early May 12th and offline until May 28th. If I don't respond to comments or accept an answer until then it isn't because I'm ignoring you or don't care. It is because I'm unable to. I wanted to post this here before my trip so I don't forget about my question in the interim and give the community time to come to a clear consensus.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not certain about *Daniel Tiger's Neighborhood*, of which I have seen very little, but events in the Neighborhood of Make Believe on *Mister Roger's Neighborhood* should certainly be on topic.  Fred Rogers was very clear with his young viewers (such as myself) that the Neighborhood of Make Believe was a separate fantasy world, where fantasy rules applied.  It explicit that it was not real, and most of the characters were puppets, and Mister Rogers sometimes discussed making up the stories that filled the Make Believe Segments.

As well as straight fantasy (such as magic spells, talking animals, and Henrietta the cat, who only said "meow" but was nonetheless intelligible to the other characters) there were also science fiction elements to the Neighborhood of Make Believe.  I recall Planet Purple, which was populated by teleporting purple pandas.  At one point, King Friday also purchased a flying electric car.  There was also a limited degree of narrative continuity to the Make Believe segments.  Characters in the Neighborhood arrived or moved away; the sets were updated, with in-universe justifications; and elements like the purple pandas and the flying car were wont to show up now and again after they had been introduced.

Comment: Daniel Tiger's Neighborhood is a direct spin-off that takes place entirely in the Neighborhood of Make Believe